# transfer the value entered in a textfield to another angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to transfer the value entered into a textfield to another in angularjs and this is my attempt but it is not working

```
<label>Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="email" required />

          <span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.userEmail.$error.required">Your email is required</span>
         <br>

         <input type="email" name="emailAccess" ng-model="{{email}}" required />
```

Kindly assist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<label>Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="email" required />

          <span class="invalid" ng-show="myForm.userEmail.$error.required">Your email is required</span>
         <br>

         <input type="email" name="emailAccess" ng-model="email" required />
```

Remove {{ and }} from last one.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

For two-direction transfer, use ng-model without brackets.

```
<input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="email" required />
<input type="email" name="emailAccess" ng-model="email" required />
```